# Ubuntu Connects with Amazon Echo as Bluetooth Speaker not Treating that as Speaker

Tags: sound, bluetooth

When I connect my Echo device with Ubuntu for the first time over Bluetooth. I was happy with sound etc. After one restart I found Echo is treating my PC as a Bluetooth speaker and in Sound settings, I can see Echo is acting like input device and not as an speaker.

Here:

[image: Sound settings]

Now can anyone please suggest me how I can solve this issue and use the Echo device back as my Bluetooth speaker?

Comment: In the output devices list, are you able to see the Amazon Echo?

Comment: no, only that dummy audio.

Comment: Please run `pactl list short sinks` on a terminal. Edit your post with the output.
(The Amazon Echo must be connected)

Comment: [omi@nuc ~]$ pactl list short sinks
0       auto_null       module-null-sink.c      s16le 2ch 44100Hz       RUNNING

Comment: That is the result. By the way, same thing happens with CentOS. Funny part is, Live Ubuntu works fine.

Answer (score 6):

Remove the Echo device from your bluetooth devices if you haven't already.

Go to the [Alexa web interface](https://alexa.amazon.com/). Go to settings, select the Echo you're trying to connect to, and click Bluetooth.

If you're computer is listed on this page, forget the device.

Then click Pair New Device. *Note*: Don't click on your computer from the web interface. This always results in the Echo pairing as an input device.

Assuming you have other speakers (or headphones available), you can run `bluetoothctl scan on | grep Echo -m 1 | head -1;espeak "Found the echo device"` to be alerted when the Echo is available to pair with.

The Echo should now show up in Ubuntu's bluetooth devices list. *Note*: Having audio playing seems to increase the success of the next step.

Finally, click on the Echo device in your bluetooth device list and connect it. It should connect as a speaker (It may take multiple attempts before it connects).

Answer (score 5):

Pair or connect to echo while playing some audio on your machine.
It is the only workaround I found at the moment.

Source [here](https://manuelfedele.github.io/posts/ubuntu-echo-plus-alexa-workaround-bluetooth-speaker/)

Comment: This actually worked for me ️.

Comment: The provided link is now broken.

Comment: There was not a lot more than said here in the link. Anyway, I fixed it. I retried, and it still work, even if it is a workaround.

Comment: This is the best answer, It actually worked for me.. as @ManuelFedele said.. please read the source.. it clearly explains.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem.
Had to install packages `apt install bluez bluez-tools pulseaudio-module-bluetooth`
Then restart pulseaudio with `killall pulseaudio` and the device was finally recognized as both input and output.